# how to create a folder in google storage? Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

This is working, but only the file is created at the root and not the folder

```
 {:ok, object} = GoogleApi.Storage.V1.Api.Objects.storage_objects_insert_simple(
      conn,
      bucket_id,
      "multipart",
      %{name: Path.basename(file_path)},
      file_path
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` parameter should be the *full* folder plus filename to store in your bucket; you're only sending the `basename(file_path)`, which is the file name that was uploaded.

A few tips:

- I say "folder" even though Goolge storage shows stored objects as if they were in folders, it's really just a key-value object store

  - you code *should* set the full path of the file - don't let user input set it
- pay attention to how the API expects [encoding of parameters](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints#encoding), which is normally handled for you by this library

  - unfortunately [a bug](https://github.com/googleapis/elixir-google-api/issues/6510) was introduced in v0.23 (and exists through at least v0.26) where they are not encoding the final path parameter correctly
- you'll want to send the correct `mime_type` in the object's meta data when you do the upload, or downloading it from the browser will result in it being sent as a binary only